# When you declare an object in javascript, how to you set a property in relation to another one

Tags: javascript, object, coding-style, modularity

This is basically the structure of my code ([based on this basically](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/)):

```
var s,
NewsWidget = {

  settings: {
    numArticles: 5
  },

  init: function() {
    // kick things off
    s = this.settings;
  }

};
```

So basically [this is is the expected usage](http://jsfiddle.net/3Gg6U/2/).

My problems is that when I'm declaring settings and want them to be in relationship to each other I can't:

```
settings: {
    numArticles: 5,
    scienceAricles: numArticles - 3
}
```

This obviously don't work either because the object is still not defined (This doesn't actually make sense, but just to exemplify what I mean):

```
scienceAricles: this.numArticles - 3
scienceAricles: s.numArticles - 3
```

So the only way I can think of right now is to do something like this:

```
var NewsWidget = {};
NewsWidget.s = {};

NewsWidget.s.numArticles = 5;
NewsWidget.s.scienceArticles = NewsWidget.s.numArticles -3;
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6q7/1/)

But I don't like this approach so much and our codebase is already based on the previous mentioned and linked architecture, so it would be a pretty big re-structure.

Am I missing something? What is the best way of doing this without changing the whole approach?

Comment: There is no way within an object literal to reference other values in the same literal. You must do what you wrote, first create and then modify. You can create additional variables outside to make it simpler, if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var numArticles = 5,
   s,
   NewsWidget = {

     settings: {
       numArticles: numArticles,
       scienceAricles: numArticles - 3
     },

     init: function() {
       // kick things off
       s = this.settings;
     }    
  };
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting hadn't though of that. I'll wait for some other answers but this pretty much what I was looking for.